# ERROR in Entry module not found

Tags: json, webpack

This is the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 322. But JSON file
>   is correct.

JSON file:

```
    {
      "name": "gl",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "GL online CV",
      "main": "index.html",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Alex Guzhyk",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "react": "^16.1.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1",
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do? i dont think these 2 are related.

Answer (score 2):

Validate your JSON to know if the format is correct.

Remove the trailing comma at the end of the collection.

```
{
      "name": "gl",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "GL online CV",
      "main": "index.html",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "Alex Guzhyk",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "react": "^16.1.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.1.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "webpack": "^3.8.1"
        }
    }
```

You can check it here:
https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank You, problem was with comas

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, you can not have a trailing comma.

**Incorrect usage**

```
"person": {
  "age": 31,
  "gender": "male",
}
```

Unlike javascript, JSON is a strict data format which **is not javascript!** It has only been derived from it.

Therefore in JSON, you are not allowed to add [a trailing comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas).

**Correct usage**

```
"person": {
  "age": 31,
  "gender": "male"
}
```